# X symmetry is not symmertrical

Tags: sculpting, mirror, mirror-modifier, dynamic-topology

I am sculpting the ear of my character but x mirroring is not symmetrical. I've selected the ear and applied all transformations but I still get the same results. Is there a solution to this? Thanks

Link: https://we.tl/t-88DvuFjC7W

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks as if your object may not be centred relative to the origin. Can you add a front view image of your whole character in Object mode showing its origin?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for responding. I've uploaded the requested picture.

Comment: As I suspected the object is not centred relative to its origin (orange dot by the feet) or to the world origin, confirmed by looking at the downloaded blend file. That applies both to every  part of your model **and** to the front reference image so it's trying to symmetrise off-centre.

Comment: I changed the origin to 'geometry to origin' and it seems to be mirroring correctly. Thank you. :)

Comment: Oh good. I wasn't sure that would work but it obviously did! The main body and head are off-centre too by the way!

Comment: Awesome, I made the correct adjustments to the body and the head. Appreciate it.